# Which element has the maximum value of a function in each interval of another vector

Tags: r

I am new user in R. I have two vectors `a` and `b`. I want to find that which elements of `b` has the global maximum value of function `y = 2b`in each interval of vector `a`.
For example

```
    a = c(1, 3, 6, 7)
    b = c(1.1, 1.8, 2.3, 4.5, 6.8, 7.9, 3.3)
```

means that `1.1, 1.8, 2.3` is between `1 and 3`, but which of them has the maximum value of function `y`, and so on...

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't clear. Could you expand a bit on your intended result? Do you just want to get the maximum value of `b` in each interval as defined by `a`? I'm lost where `y=2b` comes into this though.

Comment: I want to know which element of b has the maximum value of functio y in each interval of a. It means that because y = 4.6 at 2.3  in the first interval of a, so 2.3 is my desire result for first interval and the similar method for the next intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cut` to figure out how to cut `b` at break points provided by `a`, then `split` to make a list, one per interval, and finally `sapply` ask the question on each interval

```
> sapply(split(b, cut(b, a)), function(x) x[which.max(2*x)])
(1,3] (3,6] (6,7] 
  2.3   4.5   6.8
```

This still works if one of the intervals has zero values

```
b <- c(1.1, 1.8, 6.8, 7.9)
res <- sapply(split(b, cut(b, a)), function(x) x[which.max(2 * x)])
```

where the return is now a list with the entry `numeric()` for the interval with zero values. The result `res` could be simplified with something like

```
> res[sapply(res, length) == 0] <- NA
> unlist(res)
(1,3] (3,6] (6,7] 
  1.8    NA   6.8
```

Alternatively, the interval can be removed before searching for the maximum, `split(b, cut(b, a), drop=TRUE)`.

Comment: If I have numeric() in one of the interval, so I can not calculate the function y, so how can I fix this, because sometime with different data sets I got no value in some intervals.

Comment: @rose tried to suggest solutions, but consider editing your question to illustrate the problem and hoped-for solution.